# No free hugepages reported in hugepages when running DPDK helloworld example

Tags: linux, dpdk, huge-pages

I downloaded and built dpdk-stable-16.11.4 version (using the x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc target). I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. After setting up hugepages according to http://dpdk.org/doc/quick-start or http://dpdk.org/doc/guides-16.04/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html

```
mkdir -p /mnt/huge
mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge
echo 64 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

I can see the hugepages fine.

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge

    HugeAnonHugePages:    284672 kB
    ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
    HugePages_Total:      64
    HugePages_Free:       64
    HugePages_Rsvd:        0
    HugePages_Surp:        0
    Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

But when I run the helloWorld example, it complained about no free hugepages, see below.

```
./build/helloworld -l 0-3 -n 2
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
hello from core 1
hello from core 2
hello from core 3
hello from core 0
```

Also, the memory info showed free hugepages were all gone.

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge

    AnonHugePages:    380928 kB
    ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
    HugePages_Total:      64
    HugePages_Free:        0
    HugePages_Rsvd:        0
    HugePages_Surp:        0
    Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. 1GB Hugepages

The example complains about 1048576kB hugepages, i.e. 1GB. This is correct, you don't have 1GB pages configured as we can see in /proc/meminfo

But you do not need 1GB pages to start a DPDK application, so it just informs and continues.

#### 2. Free Hugepages

The free hugepages are all gone because if we do not specify the amount of memory to use for the DPDK application with `-m`or `--socket-mem` option, it will reserve all the available hugepages.

More on that in DPDK [Getting Started Guide here](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/build_sample_apps.html#hugepage-memory-use-by-applications).

In case the hugepages remain allocated even when the application has ended (or crashed), you can free the hugepages manually by removing files in /mnt/huge

Comment: Thanks. It worked either with `-m` or `--socket-mem` option.  Since I have 2MB pages, so I used `-m 2` or `--socket-mem=2`.  I also noticed after running the application, the page used doesn't get returned right away.  That is `HugePages_Free:       63` instead of 64.  So I rerun the app without any options but with just `--huge-unlink` and now I can see the used page is returned as `HugePages_Free:       64` in `/proc/meminfo`.